# The question is to generate a table with a dictionary. Why the square and curly brackets for key and value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is the code they provided:

```
my_dict = {'C1': [1, 2, 3], 'C2': [5, 6, 7], 'C3': [9, 10, 11]}
for row in zip(*([key] + (value) for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items()))):
    print(*row)
```

This is what i did but I also don't understand how you can do the key + value part:

```
for t in zip(*(key + value for key, value in my_dict.items())):
    print(*t)
```

This is the error i get

```
    for t in zip(*(key + value for key, value in my_dict.items())):
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Comment: `key` is of type string, `value` is of type list, you cannot do `key + value`, therefore you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using to `str()` function to convert the list to a string. This will allow you to complete your goal.

Dictionaries have the {}
Lists have the []

Comment: Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I still don't get it. Why do they use [key] + (value) , why the square and curly brackets and how does the addition work?